# Reference dynamically-named form control with form controller

Tags: angularjs

Where I have something like this (*note* this is a contrived example):

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="{{'myInput'}}" ngModel="data.myInputModel">
</form>
```

I would expect to reference it like this:

```
$scope.myForm.myInput
```

But this doesn't work, instead internally angular registers the control via `$addControl(ngModelController)` where the ngModelController object looks like this:

```
{
  $name: "{{'myInput'}}"
  ...
}
```

While I expected this:

```
{
  $name: "myInput"
  ...
}
```

I will post my workaround as an answer below, but **I'd like to know if there is a better way to handle this?**

---

**Update:** [Something similar to this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859959/validating-nested-form-in-angular), but the answer provided isn't terribly useful. My answer below might be useful to someone looking for an alternative approach.

Comment: Why do you have '' around your replacement value {{'myInput'}} should be {{myInput}}.

Comment: @JonSamwell, like I said this is a contrived example. The real use-case is inside of an ng-repeat where you have something like `name="myInput{{$index}}"`. For the purposes of this question `{{'myInput'}}` is simpler than using a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Here is my workaround:

```
.directive('dynamicName', function () {
  return {
    require: ['^form', 'ngModel'],
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      var formCtrl = ctrls[0],
          ngModelCtrl = ctrls[1];

      ngModelCtrl.$name = attrs.dynamicName;
      formCtrl.$addControl(ngModelCtrl);
    }
  }
})
```

#### And I use it like this:

```
<input dynamic-name="{{'myInput'}}" />
```